# iOS remember my decision of don't use my position in a web app

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, gps, iphone-3gs

It seems that iOS remember my decision, of not use my position in web application, also after have cleaned the cache and/or removing my webapp from home screen.

So every moment i start my webapp, iOS doesn't prompt me to use my position, in fact it "remember" always my first choice.

Is there any setting/function to avoid this behavior ?

PS: I've tested with an iPhone 3gs with iOS 4, not sure if any other version of iOS and/or iphone, have the same behavior.

Comment: Is this simply Safari that is doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is Safari. If you tell it not to use Location Services in the Settings, it should prompt again.